# html js css Square progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create square-based progressbar (like for abilities in games). 
Recently I came across svg, this code will give you the idea of what I want to accomplish:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    console.log();

    let x = 100;
    let y = 5;

    var id = setInterval(function() {

      $('#a').attr('points', `0,0 50,0 50,50 ${x},${y} 100,100 0,100 0,0`);
      y++;
      if (y >= 100) {
        x--;
        if (x < 80)
          clearInterval(id);
      }
    }, 30);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg height="100" width="100">
      <polygon  id="a" points="0,0 50,0 50,50 100,0 100,100, 0,100 0,0" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

<button>a</button>
```

here is Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vecLotgu/1/

However, with such an approach, it will be algorithmically complicated to compute the points of the polygon (as they change). 
I want to ask, is there any way to do this in pure css?
Moreover, do you have any elegant idea how to solve the point computation is the svg solution?

Thank you

Comment: You could try this with css vars, but that won't work in older browsers

Comment: It would perhaps be simpler to use a circle element masked with overflow hidden to look like a square. Here is somebody else's circular progress bar hacked to appear as a square: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxENWq (Original: https://codepen.io/JMChristensen/pen/Ablch). This would allow you to simply adjust the `strokedash-offset` and transition with CSS rather than calculate the polygon coordinates in setInterval.